# How to set up 'supertest' to test imported functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, supertest

Unlike most of the tutorials on the Internet that use

```js
app.post("/login", (req, res) => { ... });
```

I have set up routes like this

```js
import * as LoginController from './controllers/login/login';

app.post("/login", LoginController.postLogin);
```

And in the `LoginController`, it's

```js
export function postLogin(req, res) {
  ...
}
```

So, I wonder how I can do the unit testing for `postLogin(req, res)` using supertest without grabbing the `module.exports = app` from the `app.js`?

Is it possible to do something like

```js
import request from "supertest";
import { postLogin } from "./login"; // we're in src/controllers/login/login.test.js

describe("POST Login", () => {
    it("should return 200 OK", (done) => {
        request(postLogin)
            // some post data
            .expect(200, done);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to actually unit-test `postLogin` you can just mock the `req/res`-objects and pass them into the `postLogin` method.

```
describe("postLogin", () => {
    it("should not reject and return expected data", async () => {
        const reqMock = { path: "somePath", body: {} };
        const resMock = {};
        const result = await postLogin(req, res); // assuming that postLogin returns a promise
        expect(result.someProperty).to.eql(tbd);
    });
});
```

If your intent is to make an actual request through superset and validate your app's response (which is more of an integration test than a unit-test by the way), then there's no alternative to requiring the `app.js` and starting up your app.